# Mix command not found Heroku run

Tags: heroku, elixir

Deploying on Heroku a Elixir Phoenix project it is saying that `mix command not found` on command `heroku run 'POOL_SIZE=2 mix test.task'`

I pushed the code before running and followed the tutorial on elixir docs carefully.

To mention - `mix phx.server` and all other `mix` commands are workin just fine.
Elixir version: `1.11.2`

```
$ heroku run "POOL_SIZE=2 mix hello.task"
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.52.0 to 7.53.1.
Running POOL_SIZE=2 mix hello.task on ⬢ bgsites... up, run.4395 (Free)
bash: mix: command not found
```

Comment: To be clear, it's saying `bash: mix: command not found` not `bash: mix command not found`. Mix itself is reporting the error, which is then reported by bash. `hello.task` does not appear to be available

Comment: Just to confirm, is `test.task` a viable mix task for your app?  Can you run that command locally and does it show up when you do `mix help`?

Comment: What buildpack did you install in your heroku instance?